# Wikipedia API - edits or flags at a given date or period

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki-api

Is it possible to return Wikipedia API data giving a user's edit count or group membership (flag) data for a specific date, rather than for the current time?

Re counts, I'd like to be able to query for a given user's edit count up to a cut-off date time in the past.

Re flags, user account logs tend show the *removal* of a flag (sysop, bot, etc.) but often the *initial grant* of the flag is not logged. However, to be removed it must have been granted and I'd like use API calls for past times to try and find the date-time of grant.

The documentation/worked examples aren't of help in trying to assess if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible via the API. You could reconstruct it from publicly available dumps and event logs but it's a lot of work.

The [MediaWiki edit history dataset](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Analytics/Data_Lake/Edits/Mediawiki_history) includes such reconstruction. At some point it will be made publicly available; right now only researchers can [get access](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Research/Formal_collaborations) on an individual basis.

Comment: This confirms my suspicions. Sad, but answered. Techocrats don't like sharing with GenPop.